# Date format issue with vb6 on windows 7 and MS Sql database

Tags: sql-server, date, windows-7, vb6

I have a vb6 application and it linked to an MS SQL Database via Windows DSN.  The application is using rdo connection to connect to the database and tables.  Recently my users upgraded their OS to Windows 7.  Now they have an issue with the dates whenever they do a posting or updates.  Although the system default short date format is set as `dd/MM/yy`, the application keeps posting the dates to the database as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

The strange thing is that within the codes the date has already been formated per below

```
rsPO("LAST_UPDATED_DATE") = Format(Now, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")
```

so why is it still saving the date as `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: Are you looking at the values in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? If you SELECT a DATETIME value it will helpfully format the internal value as a meaningful string. That does _not_ mean it is stored as a string.

Comment: Is `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` defined as a `varchar` (or similar) or a `datetime` field?

Comment: Don't think it has anything to do with the select command. It only happens when it is updating or inserting a new record.  Moreover there were no issue when running on Windows XP.

Comment: LAST_UPDATED_DATE is defined as datetime.

Comment: If your data column is a datetime, then why would you be using any formatting at all? That's only useful if your column is storing a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try with ISO format date. It is a universal date format and works in all DBs

```
rsPO("LAST_UPDATED_DATE") = Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss")
```

Dates are not saved in "dd/mm/yyyy" or any other particular format into the Database.

You just should make sure to use a format to save it in the same manner understood by the application, the OS and the DataBase

Then you can show it the format that you like.

ISO format works ok in most cases.

Comment: ISO formats work in ALL cases.  Unfortunately, your example is not an ISO format.  It should be YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss or YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

Comment: Vb6 doesn't support YYYYMMDDD" YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss  format, So I wrote the date in a format understood for App, OS and BD.

Comment: I did not test my example at the time I wrote it, but I just tested now, and it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Date interpretation is a language thing.  It's not set by the language on the client computer.  It's set by the language of the login making the connection to the SQL database.  There are a couple ways you can change things so that it is language independent.

Since LAST_UPDATED_DATE is a DateTime, you should be able to do this:

```
rsPO("LAST_UPDATED_DATE").Value = Now
```

If not, then you should format your dates like this:  YYYYMMDD.

```
rsPO("LAST_UPDATED_DATE") = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss")
```

Read more about it here:  [Setting a standard DateFormat for SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se)

Comment: Vb6 doesn't support YYYYMMDDD" YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss format. Did you test your example?

Comment: @Gonzalo I did not test my example at the time I wrote it, but I just tested now, and it does indeed work.

Comment: Thanks all for the response.  I wish I could modify and recompile the legacy apps but unfortunately, assign to being in VB6 it was coded on a very old version of Visual Studio and uses a very legacy Crystal Report dll.  As far as possible I'm trying to refrain from recompiling the code because of the implications.  The odd thing is that in it's original form it works fine on XP and not on 7.  Does anyone else faces such issue?

Answer (score 0):

To make our developers into the context. The problem is not with stored Date in the database, but the problem happens when we call `select` for example `select * from ... where Date_import ....`. This `date_import` is getting into the database with the format *mm-dd-yyyy* by default. So the problem is with the String request SQL and not at all with your code or with how data is stored. The solution is to set all your code with *YYYY-MM-DD* instead of *DD-MM-YYYY*.